# Maven exclusion for maven-toolchains-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-toolchains-plugin

In our module say **XYZ** We included a dependency for maven toolchains plugin to have our Jenkins build run with a specific JDK version. But once we included this toolchain dependency it further bring in lot of other dependencies (See screenshot below) when we include **XYZ** module as a dependency in another project.

Some of these dependencies which came due to toolchain like `slf4j-jdk14-1.5.6.jar` and `slf4j-nop-1.5.3.jar` are causing issues like ***SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.*** when we deploy the application.

**Maven dependency we added for toolchain plugin**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Dependency tree of maven-toolchains-plugin**

[image]

So, my question is if I exclude `org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain` or `org.apache.maven:maven-core` (as shown below) while adding the toolchains plugin dependency in XYZ would it cause any issue with respect to my other dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Having a dependency to maven-toolchains-plugin is simply wrong. No need to run toolchains.

Comment: Related to Jenkins. If you like to build with different JDK than Jenkins is Running you have to go via Freestyle Job Type or using the pipeline....

Comment: @khmarbaise, After looking at your suggestion to not add dependency for `maven-toolchains-plugin` went on to check the this https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html that also does not talk about adding the dependency. I followed a company internal confluence page which mentioned to include it which was wrong. After removing the dependency it is good now. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Glad to help. Furthermore If you are unsure please consult the users mailing of Apache Maven and don't rely on internal docs etc. which (unfortunately to say) are usually simply wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on @khmarbaise's comments above.

Having a dependency to `maven-toolchains-plugin` was simply wrong.
I went on to check this documentation: [Guide to Using Toolchains](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) that too does not talk about adding the dependency.

I followed a company internal confluence page which mentioned to include it which was wrong.